# HTML5 video player on Firefox

Tags: html, firefox, video

I have a video player in HTML5, pretty simple.

```
<video width="470" height="265" preload="none" controls="controls" id="video_player" poster="assets/posters/finished_jk.jpg">   
        <source type="video/webm" src="assets/videos/finished_jk.webm"></source>    
        <source type="video/ogg" src="assets/videos/finished_jk.ogv"></source>      
        <source type="video/mp4" src="assets/videos/finished_jk.mp4"></source>
        Your browser doesn't support videos
</video>
```

I have an issue with Firefox. When I click the play button, it's going directly to the end of the video.

It works with Chrome, Safari and Opera.

Thanks

Comment: can you host this somewhere visible so we can check with the specific assets. Also, what version of FF and what platform?

Comment: Unfortunately it's not possible for me to host the asset. I'm using Firefox 19.0.2

Comment: do you have (eg) Big Buck Bunny versions where you can demo the problem? Have you tried changing .ogv to .ogg?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem came from the encoder software I used.

I used "Miro Video Converter" to convert my mp4 video in webm format. I tried with another one and it works fine.

Comment: Glad to hear it's sorted. It's always a good test to simply drag the video file into the browser in question to see if it plays. If not, you know it's the file itself.